# How to use multithreading to download 1000+ .txt files in Python quickly

Tags: python, multithreading, download, python-multithreading

I have a .txt file with a list of 1000+ URLs of .txt files that I need to download and then index by word. The indexing is fast, but the downloading is a huge bottleneck. I tried using urllib2 and urllib.request, but downloading a single text file with either of these libraries takes .25-.5 seconds per file (on average the files are around 600 words/3000 characters of text)

I realize I need to utilize multithreading (as a concept) at this point, but I don't know how I would go about doing this in Python. At this point I'm downloading them one at a time, and it looks like this:

```
        with open ('urls.txt', 'r') as f:                   # urls.txt is the .txt file of urls, one on each line
            for url in f:
                response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
                data = response.read()
                text = data.decode()
                # .. and then index the text
```

This project prompt allowed me to select any language. I chose Python because I thought it would be faster. The sample output I received listed the total indexing time at around 1.5 seconds, so I assume this is approximately the benchmark they would like applicants to reach. Is it even possible to achieve such a fast runtime for this number of downloadable files in Python, on my machine (which has 4 cores)?

edit (including more information about the indexing):

Each .txt file I'm downloading contains a review of a college. Ultimately I want to index all of the terms in each review, such that when you search by term, you get back a list of all of the colleges whose reviews contain the term, and how many times that term was used in reviews for a given college. I have nested dictionaries such that the other key is the search term, and the outer value is a dictionary. The inner dictionary's term is the name of a college, and the inner dictionary's value is the number of times the term has appeared in reviews for that college.

Comment: Try [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are exactly doing while indexing the text, and whether data should should be exchanged between threads, or if you are writing to a single file/variable (a lock should be used), but this should work:

```py
import threading
import urllib.request

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = f.read().splitlines()
    
def download_index(url, lock):
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()
    text = data.decode()
    #indexing
    with lock:
        #access shared resources

n = 2 #number of parallel connections
chunks = [urls[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(urls) + n - 1) // n )]

lock = threading.Lock()
                
for chunk in chunks:
    threads = []
    for url in chunk:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=download_index, args=(url, lock,))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

Note that you should take into account how many connections you should have at a time, as you would most likely get blocked for having 1000+ requests happening at the same time. I don't know the ideal number, but play around with the `n` number and see what works. Or use proxies.

Edit: added a lock

Comment: Thank you! This is excellent. I implemented it in my program and it brought the index time down to around 7 seconds total. I have n around 600; I found that raising it much more than that started slowing things down. I added an edit to explain exactly what I'm indexing. The program is running, but the index is not always displaying the correct word count. I've written locks in c, but is this something you can do relatively easily in python?

Comment: I have added a lock to the script, but i don't recommend using it for the whole indexing process. Just for when accessing shared resources to avoid slowing things down.

Comment: thank you! that's great. I should be able to tailor it from here. I appreciate your help! it's nice to see that adding locks is pretty straightforward in python